# Misnamed MS SQL server MSBD and Model DB log file names during move

Tags: sql-server

I've made an interesting problem for myself on SQL 2008R2.  I moved my MSDB and Model databases to a new drive, but in the process of doing so I transposed the log file names for each and they are now reversed.  SQL will start, and I can check database file names with the following script:

```
SELECT name,
physical_name AS CurrentLocation,
state_desc
FROM sys.master_files
```

Which confirms the flipped names.  The script that I used to cause my problem returns a "database does not exist" error, however.

```
ALTER DATABASE msdb
MODIFY FILE (NAME = MSDBLog, FILENAME = ‘F:\SQLLogs\MSDBLog.ldf’);
GO
ALTER DATABASE Model
MODIFY FILE (NAME = ModelLog, FILENAME = ‘F:\SQLLogs\ModelLog.ldf’);
GO
```

Swapping the file names to match the misconfiguration results in SQL not starting.

Any thoughts on how to fix this, without resorting to a system database rebuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy to say that I worked out a solution to my problems.  One of the fundamental hangups that I was hitting was I was mistaking the error message "The file does not exist" to reference the database file itself, rather than the logical file name within the database.  I will provide below the inspection script that I drafted that got me over the hump.

Steps I took to ultimately solve this:

1. Turned off TCP/IP connections and turned on Named Pipes, to ensure only local access to the DB.
2. Started SQL from the command line with 3608 trace flag, to prevent any other databases other than master from being brought up.  I needed to start and stop SQL quite a few times, so I kept this CMD line up.  "NET START MSSQLSERVER /T3608" and "NET STOP MSSQLSERVER"
3. Ran my script to show me the naming on the databases (listed by ID, 3 and 4) 
   and then appropriately modified and ran the name correction scripts. See below.

The script that show me the precise problems that I had caused myself with my transpositions:

```
SELECT database_id, name,
physical_name AS CurrentLocation,
state_desc
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = 3 OR database_id = 4
go
```

database_id 3 is Model, 4 is MSDB

With that in mind, substituting the corrected information into the following scripts worked (albeit with a few service restarts)

```
ALTER DATABASE msdb
MODIFY FILE (NAME = MSDBLog, FILENAME = 'D:\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBLog.ldf');
GO
ALTER DATABASE msdb
MODIFY FILE (NAME = MSDBData, FILENAME = 'D:\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBData.mdf');
GO
ALTER DATABASE model
MODIFY FILE (NAME = modellog, FILENAME = 'D:\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf');
GO
ALTER DATABASE model
MODIFY FILE (NAME = modeldev, FILENAME = 'D:\MSSQL\DATA\model.mdf');
GO
```

In some cases where the NAME was wrong, I needed to use (please note the swap below - DONT USE unless you have this exact swapping issue):

```
ALTER DATABASE model
MODIFY FILE (NAME = msdbdata, NEWNAME = modeldev );
GO
```